# Is there any way to write a compiler without Abstract Syntax Tree in front end?

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, programming-languages, abstract-syntax-tree

I am learning about Programming Language Creation. I found a lot information about this on the internet and e-books. But i have a question here. Lexical analysis and parsing are the first steps in creating a language. When creating a parser, the **Abstract Syntax Tree** is used directly ( As mentioned everywhere ). Can i create a parser without using **AST**?

That is,

```
Lexical Analysis -> Parsing -> Code Generation -> ....
```

What are the side effects of doing this? Why is AST so useful?

Thanks to everyone !

Comment: Yes indeed, and I've done it several times. If your semantic processing requirements are trivial you can just do them and the code generation in line in a recursive descent parser.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thank you :)  May i have further information? A link or book or something? FOr example if you put (1 + 1 * 10) in there, can you get the correct answer? (ans.11 / not 1+1 = 2, 2 * 10 =  20)?

Comment: Yes of course. Just write a recursive expression parser, output PUSH instructions for the identifiers or literals, and the appropriate operator instructions as you encounter them after parsing both operands. The result will be essentially RPN that evaluates in the correct order for operator precedence. Green Dragon book is the standard reference for this entire topic. AST is useful when you want to do more, e.g. constant folding or other optimizations, or when you need to do flow analysis &c before code generation.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Thank you very much :) you solved a big problem for me.